# How to show metadata of a document in liferay

Tags: liferay, document-library

I have a custom document library portlet, where I have to show metadata of attached document in another page, can anyone suggest how can I show these fields?

Comment: I hope version is Liferay 6.x.

Comment: @PrakashK yeap version is 6.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DLFileEntryMetadataLocalServiceUtil`.

```
DLFileEntryMetadata fileEntryMetadata = DLFileEntryMetadataLocalServiceUtil
                      .getFileEntryMetadata(ddmStructure.getStructureId(), fileVersionId);

Fields fields = StorageEngineUtil.getFields(fileEntryMetadata.getDDMStorageId());
```